# Default rspec request stub response not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've created a test with

```
rails g integration_test index --webrat
```

This creates the file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Indices" do
  describe "GET /indices" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      visit indices_path
      response.status.should be(200)
    end
  end
end
```

That's all fine, but the only problem is that this test fails even though `indices_path` exists:

```
Failure/Error: response.status.should be(200)
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass
```

So it seems like `response` is `nil`.

I can still use `page` (e.g. `page.should have_content` works perfectly), but not `response`.  I'd really just like to know that the response status was 200.  Can I use something other than `response`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `page` is available, it looks like you may have `capybara` instead of `webrat`. You can try this:

```
page.status_code.should be 200
```